# problem to pop up a window in firefox plugin

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

hi
  I am creating firefox plugin.I have one button-1.png image and I have added it to customize toolbar.I have used one button.xul file to add button in toolbar.I have also used chrome.manifest, install.rdf,button.css,button.js.
It is showing button in toolbar,I dragged that button and dropped on toolbar.
Now my question is, when I click on that button, I want to pop up a small window.
so please tell me,what should I write in button.xul & button.js to pop up a small window.
How will I get a pop up window,when I click on a button?
What changes I need to do in button.xul & button.js?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the window.open method to open a popup window. Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Creating_a_Window) link. If you want to open a popup(and not a window) then you can use a [panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/panel). You can anchor a panel to an element (say button) when opening it using the [openpopup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/panel#m-moveTo) method. Some examples are available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide/Panels) as well.